# Encrypting connection strings in multiple ASP.NET MVC configuration files?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am working on an MVC web application which of course has multiple configuration files. My connection string is there in a number of files.

How I can encrypt connection string in all files? Will aspnet_regiis automatically encrypt in all files or just in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this answer I proposed, it provides some information and useful links for Encryption in configuration files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19052327/375304