# How does IIS Config File Encryption work?

Tags: iis-7, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I'm trying to understand how the `aspnet_regiis.exe` tool "encrypts" Web.config files.

Here is the documentation for how to use the tool:

- Encryption:

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986855.aspx
- Decryption:

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986792.aspx

I'm looking for answers to questions this documentation does not address:

- Does this only work for Web.config files?
- What exactly is encrypted? The whole config file?
- Does IIS automatically know how to decrypt encrypted config files?
- What encryption algorithms are used?
- Are there any encryption keys (and/or passwords)? Where are they?
- Can I encrypt on one machine and decrypt on another? (Or does it rely on a secret key somewhere on the server?)

Comment: *"Can I encrypt on one machine and decrypt on another? (Or does it rely on a secret key somewhere on the server?)"* It probably uses the keys in *machine.config*, so I'd bet you can't encrypt in one machine and then decrypt in another unless you edit machine configuration file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Does this only work for Web.config files?

I think so, but a simple test will give you a sure answer. (**update**: the tool asssumes there is web.config file. If you need to encrypt another file like app.config, just rename it to web.config).

- What exactly is encrypted? The whole config file?

You can specify sections that will be encrypted (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link).

- Does IIS automatically know how to decrypt encrypted config files?

Yes ([same link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

- What encryption algorithms are used?

You can choose a provider of your choice ([same link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

- Are there any encryption keys (and/or passwords)? Where are they?

Yes there are if you use the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link for more info.

- Can I encrypt on one machine and decrypt on another? (Or does it rely
  on a secret key somewhere on the server?)

Yes, using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider it is possible.

For more general information on Protected Configuration, please refer to [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I found that the tool assumes there is a `Web.config` file in the specified folder.  The trick to encrypt `App.config` files is to rename it to `Web.config`, encrypt it, then rename it back.

Comment: I clicked the link to see what encryption algorithm is used but its still a bit vague. Seems the default is DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider which uses the Windows Data Protection API https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API, which "allows developers to encrypt keys using a symmetric key derived from the user's logon secrets, or in the case of system encryption, using the system's domain authentication secrets." ... so by default aspnet_regiis is machine specific unless you specify a different configuration provider